# Can C# apps run without the .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net

I intend to learn C# and start coding Windows .exe applications, but the only thing that is holding me back is that not all potential users have the .NET framework installed and therefore would be unable to run my application.

Is there any way around it?

Thanks!

Comment: No there is not. <snappish>But yes, there is. Just use Mono.</snappish>

Comment: Perhaps if you would clarify who you're targeting that you don't think will have the framework, we could provide some more constructive solutions for how/whether to use C# to develop for those users.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

YES, there was [XenoCode](http://www.xenocode.com/) that can wrap everything that your app needs and runs it in as a standalone.  I don't know what kind of dirty tricks they use, but there IS a way.

Now it's [Spoon](http://spoon.net/Studio/)

From their site:

> Spoon Studio
>
> Easily virtualize all of your applications for instant,
>   zero-install delivery on Spoon Server and Spoon.net.
>
> Spoon Studio lets you convert your existing software applications into virtual applications
>   that run with no installs, conflicts, or dependencies.

BTW, I'm in no way affiliated with them - just curious if the community will accept it or flame it.

Comment: At a $2400 price-tag for SPOON Studio -- wouldn't it be easier to have your users install the .NET runtimes, instead? They are free (and so, too is the SPOON-built apps, but you now have a cost to pass on to your customers).

Comment: That's not a flame, that's pointing out a disadvantage of something causing $2400. Now if Michael had said nasty things about the producers for charging $2400, or about you for suggesting it, then that would be a flame.

Comment: OK, sorry, by flame I mean that someone downvotes me for suggesting overpriced piece of bloatware.  I know of xenocode back when they were cool obfuscating tool...

Comment: @daniel-mosmondor - I didn't downvote, just noting for the OP or future web-crawlers. You answered his question. I just think he should be asking _other_ questions....

Answer (score 17):

No.  c# *only* target .NET (or a comparable framework, such as mono).  As an aside, Win7 comes with .NET preinstalled, and I believe Vista did as well.  There are also a ton of MS apps which require .NET.  It's getting near ubiquitous on windows machines, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 15):

C# is just a programming language. From a strictly technical point of view, someone could develop a C# compiler that targets the Windows API or <insert your target platform here> directly. Sure, it would be a lot of effort because C# was designed to fit .NET, which means the compiler writer would essentially have to re-implement .NET to provide all C# features.

From a practical point of view, you just want to use C# to target either .NET or Mono.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, with .NET Native.

Instead of compiling to intermediate language, it will compile to native code and run with statically linked .NET libraries. Therefore, there will be no .NET Runtime requirements for end users.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn642499.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397(v=vs.110).aspx

Does not work before Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft started shipping .NET 2.0 with XP since 2005. So, even if your target machine was bought somewhere within the last 8 years, it should still have .NET.

If you are targetting the linux machines on the other hand, there is the mono framework available for that. You don't even have to include it, most repositories like ubuntu, debian, etc. has packages available for mono in their repositories. All you have to do is make your own package dependent on Mono runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about C#. It's about whether you want to develop managed or unmanaged applications. C# is the choice for developing managed applications which run on .NET Framework.

If you want to avoid it, you can go to Visual C++ (without .NET) development using [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)

However, [.NET framework comes pre-installed with latest Os like Win 7 these days](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**NO** as simple as that

Everybody might say that it is already installed/ or you need the runtime. But that means **YOU NEED IT**

Comment: Why would the users not be able to install the .NET framework?

Comment: That was not the question **can C# apps run without .NET framework?**

Comment: I suppose the reason people fight over how to vote on this answer is because you could statically link the runtime in the binary? But even then, wouldn't this answer still be correct, since the runtime is still *there*?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft makes a redistributable installer that installs the version of .NET that you require.  It bloats your install, but it's pretty much the only way to do what you need.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need the .NET Runtime. However, [most of the PCs](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowManyPCsInTheWorldHaveTheNETFrameworkInstalled.aspx) running windows already have it.