# Run .Net Programs without .net framework or convert them to this purpose

Tags: c#, .net, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can C# apps run without the .NET framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306997/can-c-apps-run-without-the-net-framework)

How can I convert or compile my programs to run on computers that don't have the .net framework?

Is there any way to compile my managed code to native?

Is there any way to compile my managed code and managed libraries to a native application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. .NET Applications ALWAYS require the .NET Framework to be installed. There is no way to convert them to natives

Take a look @ http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/faq/#framework.required

which was posted by Jon Skeet on a [similar post](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/248677-convert-net-binary-native-winapi)

Comment: It is not impossible!I'm looking for the solution.

Comment: Good Luck! :) Please share your solution if you find it coz many will be thrilled to know the answer :)